# GCC: 'multiple definition' Issue with gcc 4.8 version

Tags: c, gcc

Recently we have moved our gcc version from 4.1.x to 4.8.3.
Some of my team mates are working on RH5.X and others are working on RH6.5 Versioned machines.

I notice that, on RH 5.X machine. when we try to build the code we are facing following issue while creating dynamic library.

**PS:-** We are not hitting this issue on RH6.X machines.

**Log:-**

codec_main.c.text+0x0): multiple definition of `vprintf'
/local/workspace/first/branch/dsc/cmd_parse.o:cmd_parse.c.text+0x510): first defined here
/local/workspace/first/branch/dsc/codec_main.o: In function`getchar':
codec_main.c.text+0x40): multiple definition of `getchar'
/local/workspace/first/dsc/cmd_parse.o:cmd_parse.c.text+0x550): first defined here
/local/workspace/first/branch/lpddr5_branch/src/main/cvip/build/Linux/Release/lib/extlibs/dsc/codec_main.o: In function`fgetc_unlocked':
codec_main.c.text+0x70): multiple definition of `fgetc_unlocked'

Can you please help?

Comment: Need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Could be object files from a build on another system. Try doing a clean build.

Comment: every time we are doing clean build... Not sure why this issue is hitting on RH5.x machines.